# App not sending location from Foreground service on Android 10

Tags: android, android-location, android-10.0

My app is targetting API 28. I have a foreground service sending location updates.

The app stops sending locations when the following conditions are met:

- Running on Android 10
- App is in background
- Location Permissions were selected as "Allow only while using the app"

On running

> adb shell dumpsys package *packageName*

I see that

> android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION: granted=false

From the documentation, it appears that the "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" permission was backward compatible.

How do I fix this issue? Is there a way to disable the tri-state permission request?

Comment: Do you have `android:foregroundServiceType="location"` on the `<service>` in the manifest? https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#app-access-device-location

Comment: I see a lint error `unknow attribute android:foregroundServiceType` and the app crashes

Comment: Regarding the Lint complaint, your `compileSdkVersion` should be set to 29. In terms of the crash, examine Logcat. You may want to review [the background location documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background) to see how best to handle this on Android 10.

Comment: If your app targets API28 you must choose "Allow all the time" to receive location updates while in the background. Then ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION will be granted. And, if you want only two state, then you need to change target SDK to 29, enable foregroundService=location in Manifest and omit ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you that fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

Per https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#app-access-device-location

> An app is considered to be accessing location in the background unless one of the following conditions is satisfied:
>
> - An activity belonging to the app is visible.
> - The app is running a foreground service that has declared a foreground service type of location.

You're using a foreground service to get location updates but (I assume) you haven't told the OS that, so it believes you're accessing the location in the background. All you need to do is declare that your foreground service processes location.

```
<service android:name="com.example.MyForegroundService"
         android:foregroundServiceType="location"/>
```

Now when your service is running, the OS treats your app as being in the foreground for the purposes of auditing location access - and you don't need `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`.